# Dropping SQLite index with fmbd on iOS fails with SQLITE_LOCKED

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

I'm having some trouble dropping an index I've created in SQLite in an iOS application. I'm using [fmdb](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

When attempting to drop an index, `sqlite3_step` always returns `SQLITE_LOCKED`. As a result, fmdb gets caught in an infinite loop where it continuously attempts to retry the drop statement (every single time, `sqlite3_step` returns `SQLITE_LOCKED`), and the statement never succeeds.

As far as I know, there are no other processes touching the database and statements right before the drop statement work without a problem. What am I missing?

Here's pretty much a verbatim copy of the code that's failing:

```
[db open];
/* ... */
[db executeUpdate:@"DROP INDEX IF EXISTS bookmark_hash_idx;"];
[db close];
```

`db` is a pointer to a sqlite database in my documents directory.

Here's the relevant code from fmdb, if that's useful:

```
do {
    rc      = sqlite3_step(pStmt);
    retry   = NO;

    if (SQLITE_BUSY == rc || SQLITE_LOCKED == rc) {
        // this will happen if the db is locked, like if we are doing an update or insert.
        // in that case, retry the step... and maybe wait just 10 milliseconds.
        retry = YES;
        if (SQLITE_LOCKED == rc) {
            rc = sqlite3_reset(pStmt);
            if (rc != SQLITE_LOCKED) {
                NSLog(@"Unexpected result from sqlite3_reset (%d) eu", rc);
            }
        }
        /* ... */
    }
    /* ... */
} while (retry);
```

Comment: You aren't trying to write a file in the app bundle, are you?

Comment: Try using `sqlite3_exec` instead of `sqlite3_step` to update the schema.

Comment: Nope. It's in my documents directory.

Comment: @rmaddy just tried, same result. :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have open result sets which is blocking the DROP INDEX to go through. From SQLite [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/unlock_notify.html):

> The "DROP TABLE" Exception
>
> When a call to sqlite3_step() returns SQLITE_LOCKED, it is almost always appropriate to call sqlite3_unlock_notify(). There is however, one exception. When executing a "DROP TABLE" or "DROP INDEX" statement, SQLite checks if there are any currently executing SELECT statements that belong to the same connection. If there are, SQLITE_LOCKED is returned. In this case there is no "blocking connection", so invoking sqlite3_unlock_notify() results in the unlock-notify callback being invoked immediately. If the application then re-attempts the "DROP TABLE" or "DROP INDEX" query, an infinite loop might be the result.

You should call `closeOpenResultSets` on your `FMDatabase` object to ensure all open result sets are closed before dropping the indexes.

Comment: Is there any way to see which open result set is causing the lock?

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside FMDatabase where you're seeing SQLITE_LOCKED, and log it as `po self->_openResultSets`.

Comment: @Dan - just curious, was open result sets the problem?

Comment: Hey @Anurag, sorry I haven't gotten back. I'm going to give this a shot in a couple of hours. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You were right. There was an open result set. Oddly enough, it's a pragma query that I'm using to track migrations. `po rs.query => $0 = 0x0020d1c8 PRAGMA user_version`. Now I just have to figure out why that PRAGMA query isn't finishing before this one starts. Thanks again!

Comment: Did you step through the result set by calling [resultSet next]? for the PRAGMA query?